# Can anybody explain this statement - "The point of all lambdas is deferred execution"

Tags: java, java-8

I was going through an example in "**Java SE 8 for the Really Impatient: Programming with Lambdas**".

> Let us look at a simple example. Suppose you log an event:
>
> ```
> logger.info("x: " + x + ", y: " + y);
> ```
>
> What happens if the log level is set to suppress INFO messages? The message string is computed and passed to the info method, which then decides to throw it away. Wouldn’t it be nicer if the string concatenation only happened when necessary?
>
> Running code only when necessary is a use case for lambdas. The standard idiom is to wrap the code in a no-arg lambda:
>
> ```
> () -> "x: " + x + ", y: " + y
> ```
>
> The following method provides lazy logging:
>
> ```
> public static void info(Logger logger, Supplier<String> message) {
> if (logger.isLoggable(Level.INFO))
>   logger.info(message.get());
> }
> ```
>
> We use the `isLoggable` method of the `Logger` class to decide whether INFO messages should be logged. If so, we invoke the lambda by calling its abstract method, which happens to be called get.

So what I don't understand is - we could have used the `logger.isLoggable(Level.INFO)` in the Example 1 (the code which does not use lambdas) and the message string will be computed only if we the `logger.isLoggable(Level.INFO)` is satisfied.

```
logger.info("x: " + x + ", y: " + y);
```

What was the use of using lambdas in this case?

Comment: So you don't need an `if`.

Comment: Keep in mind many lambdas are just as replaceable with actual methods (and thusly method referenced where appropriate). Though not so much in the example quoted.

Answer (score 6):

As far as I can tell this is entirely about `Supplier` and the way you can postponed the execution. The much better example IMO would be the `Optional` two methods: `orElse` and `orElseGet`.

`orElse` returns `T` or in your example case a `String`; on the other hand `orElseGet` returns a `Supplier<T>`, computed only when needed (when the Optional is actually missing):

```
public T orElseGet(Supplier<? extends T> supplier) {
    return value != null ? value : supplier.get();
}
```

The difference here is that `orElse` computes the value *always*, sort of like *eagerly*; even if it's not needed.

Answer (score 4):

> we could have used the logger.isLoggable(Level.INFO) in the Example 1 and the message string will be computed only if we the logger.isLoggable(Level.INFO) is satisfied.

That is true, yes, but only if you actually check the `isLoggable` for every log call:

```
if (logger.isLoggable(Level.INFO))
   logger.info("x: " + x + ", y: " + y);

if (logger.isLoggable(Level.INFO))
   logger.info("another log entry");
```

So you are basically requiring users to explicitly check the log level *for every log call*. There is also no way to actually enforce users to check it all the time, so you would need to *also* check the log level inside the method. And as you can probably imagine, this becomes very verbose if you end up having to add an `if` for every single log call.

On the other hand, if you are using a lambda, you can move that condition inside the `info` method, so you do *not* have to check the log level explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

By using `logger.isLogable( Level.Info )` for every info level log, to be performance wise, the code would have looked like:

```
if( logger.isLogable( Level.Info ) )
{
    logger.info( "x: " + x + ", y: " + y );
}
```

It would have introduced additional difficulty to keep every info log to write in given way. Specifically, imagine software, where various different logging levels could be used (easy to make a mistake in if statement & actual logger meth used).

Whilst using deferred functionality, as shown in book:

```
logger.info( ( ) -> "x: " + x + ", y: " + y );
```

The above deferred functionality, is actually not executing String concatenation, unless `logger.isLogable( Level.Info )` is true (in subsequent method). Therefore, essentially is faster as only method's reference is sent and String concatenation only executed once needed.

Answer (score 0):

According to the JavaSE8 documentation for the Logger class:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/logging/Logger.html

In my own words: (though you are strongly advised to read the documentation too)

In the Logger class, there are overloaded methods for each "logging" method. Those methods, instead of taking a message String as input, they take a Supplier FunctionalInterface implementation. Any FunctionalInterface can be replaced by a lambda expression or a method reference. These special Logger class methods, **invoke the body of the lambda** (or the method reference's code if you choose to use a method reference) **only if the message is actually going to be logged based on the "effective log level"**.
This is the way, the Logger class helps you avoid constucting messages in cases when the log level does not let the message be logged. So, the message construction computation effort is not needed. This is the mechanism that is usually called **deferred execution** or **lazy execution** or **laziness**. Though all these expressions may also refer to simply a delayed execution, until the execution result is actually needed. Not necessarily a "conditional execution", or **one that happens only when certain conditions are me**t.

You can identify these methods by looking for Supplier in their prototype.

Your example does not use the Java8 concept of lambda expressions and thus the String concatenation will be performed regardless or whether the log will be actually written or not.

```
//example 1: (your example)
logger.info("x: " + x + ", y: " + y);
```

If on the other hand you used Java8 lambdas the code would be like this:

```
//example 2:
logger.info((x,y) -> "x: " + x + ", y: " + y);
```

Please note, that in example 1 you are using a different method of the Logger class than the method I am using in example 2!

in example 1 you are using the method:

```
public void info(String msg)
```

while in example 2 I am using:

```
public void info(Supplier<String> msgSupplier)
```

Maybe it is a bit out of scope for this question but I think its also worth mentioning two more things:

1. deferred execution usually makes sense when you have a major benefit in your application. This could be true, if for instance:
   a - the computation required to "supply" the logged message is very expensive or 
   b - the program passes from this point of code many many times. In which case the computation becomes cumulatively expensive, even when you do a simple String concatenation. 
   Otherwise, if you have a call like the one you described, and expect it to be called rarely, there is no real reason to resort to deferred execution at all.
    
   In other words, lambdas and deferred execution are there to solve problems not for aesthetic purposes. There are, though, educational purposes for this kind of code.
2. What I am actually doing in example 2 is quite more complicated than what you were doing in example 1. Why is that?
    
   Lambda expressions can substitute method references and FunctionalInterface arguments. FunctionalInterfaces are those that have just one method in them like Supplier.
   So, in the body of the lambda I am defining the code which "overrides" the **Supplier**'s **get()** method in addition to returning the result String and stating where this should happen. Valid types for x and y are anything that can be concatenated to String.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the method signatures in your suggested case:

logger.info(message)
logger.info(level, message)

what you are suggesting is the option where based on logger.isLoggable() we can call logger.info(message) but what you have overlooked is the expression to generate that message parameter which is what we assume is an expensive operation. So logger.info(level, () -> message) is the call where even though the api call has two parameter but the second paramter is not evauated before the function execution. In your example the message = "x: " + x, "y: " + y is executed before the call enters the first check logger.isloggable and thus causes unnecessary evaluation of an expensive statement which could be deffered using a Lambda expression.